# I want to change the current number in php and publish it in a different format

Tags: php, format, numbers

PHP can't recognize `1.299.00`

TRY(generated by number_format) but only `1.299,00` TRY ,

What's the general solution for this problem?

but this number is available `(28,90)` but I just want to change what I mentioned above.

```
$num = 1.299,00;
echo number_format ( $num, 2, ",", "." );
```

isn't working.

Comment: Maybe instead of trying to change formatted number which is string make changes to number and use number format only to display result; `$num = 1299.00; $num+=133.99; echo number_format($num, 2,',','.');`

Comment: YES, PHP can't recognize 1.299.00 because it's not a number. Make it a number, and then format using number_format()